# Best practice for API interface: Pass an array or object to work with?

Tags: php, api, oop, architecture

I'm working on a payment library that will allow me to implement any payment processor through  the same interface. The issue I have now is that I would like to improve the way the data that is feed to the processors. Right now it's an array and I'm not happy with that array. The issue is is if you don't know all fields in advance you'll end up with notices or the processor code itself will need a hell of checks. The idea is to be able to take any kind of data structure because it differs between applications and make it work with the processors but also to ensure the processors get the data feed they need.

My idea now is to change that to an object. The object will come with a limited set of fields all processors require and have usually in common but the object could be extended to take additional fields.

The advantage of that would be that I can validate in the processor that it gets a payment object passed and it could validate if it implements all required fields, if not throw an exception.

So the question is now if this is a good approach or is there any better and fail save way to make sure all processors can rely on the passed data?

Comment: Downvoted? After just seconds? Wtf? Are people even reading the content besides the title before they vote down without proving a reason?

Comment: That a question here on SO? Wtf? Are people even reading the FAQ besides do anything on their own before asking holes in the sky? - Sorry for the irony but I miss substance in your question. In PHP an array can be pretty much the same as an object and you need to be way more specific to differ between the two. And it depends which of the two is better on a lot of context that you don't share here. Very subjective way to ask therefore and not constructive. You will see that mirrored in the quality of the answers, too.

Comment: I'm pretty OK with two of the 4 answers so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I might use an architecture similar to the following:

Class `payment_data` -> This class would have all common fields and likely provide some common data validation, you could also subclass this with specific processor-specific implementation where certain processors can accept additional data for processor-specific logic.  There would be no need to even pass this object to the payment processing logic if it was not able to be successfully constructed according to your validation rules.

Interface `payment_processor` -> This interface would define common methods that any of your processor-specific implementing classes would need to be able to handle the base `payment_data` object.

Processor-specific classes implementing `payment_processor` -> These classes would all be able to handle a basic `payment_data` object, but might optionally be able to be passed a processor-specific subclass of `payment_data` that implements additional features for that processor.

Comment: This is very close to what I came up with so far.

Comment: It is probably a pretty stable approach and one that should at least allow you flexibility in design as you find yourself adding more payment processors, or needing to customize logic for specific payment processors.  Of course you might also want to have some helper factory classes.  For example, say you need to determine which payment processor to use based on the data provided to you by the end user. It would be nice to have a class that would use whatever logic you dictated to instantiate the appropriate `payment_data` and `payment_processor` classes.

Comment: I finally ended up by implementing a way to set fields to the processor Processor::set() and Processor::validateFields() that will validate the set values before the actual pay/refund/whatever call is made. And yes I have a factory for the processors. :) The only downside here is that I'll always need a mapping between the data coming from an app to the processors because the structure will differ from app to app.

Answer (score 1):

I've done exactly what you are doing and I stuck with arrays. Arrays are very fast to check if any required "fields" are missing. If the array keys are the field names, create an array of the required fields and use that to test for the presence of the required fields.

```
function loadData($data) {
     static $rqd_fields = array('field1','field2','field3');
     $passed_fields = array_keys($data);
     $missing_fields = array_diff($rqd_fields, $passed_fields);
     if ( count($missing_fields)>0 ) {
         // error, return $missing_fields
     } else {
         // ok, continue
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

An object is a good approach; it's general enough that it offers you quite a bit of flexibility.  Be sure to code to an interface, to maximize flexibility.

Of course how you design the object matters...

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea.  I recommend you use a model with a __construct of all the elements required which you istantiate, and inject the model (which is of course an object) as needed anywhere else.  This way you could use a variety of models with your interface very easily.